# Could not create connection to database server - JDBC Driver in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, mysql, android-studio, jdbc

java.sql.SQLNonTransientConnectionException: Could not create connection to database server. Attempted reconnect 3 times. Giving up.

Hello i am trying to connect to a database on my android application, i have run the exact same code in normal intellij and other programs before and it connects but this time it does not want to connect.
I have tried different databases different Source/Target Compatibility versions.
I added the JBC library into the module but no luck.

Anyone has an idea?

this is the code

```
        try {
        if (connection != null && !connection.isClosed()) {
            return;
        }
        String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/test?autoReconnect=true&useSSL=false";
        String user = "root";
        String password = "password";
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        connection = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, password);
        statement = connection.createStatement();
    } catch (SQLException | ClassNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

2020-07-01 08:52:23.348 2785-2785/com.jends.mcshopplus W/System.err: Loading class `com.mysql.jdbc.Driver'. This is deprecated. The new driver class is` com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver'. The driver is automatically registered via the SPI and manual loading of the driver class is generally unnecessary.
2020-07-01 08:52:27.654 2785-2785/com.jends.mcshopplus W/System.err: java.sql.SQLNonTransientConnectionException: Could not create connection to database server. Attempted reconnect 3 times. Giving up.
2020-07-01 08:52:27.655 2785-2785/com.jends.mcshopplus W/System.err:     at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:110)
2020-07-01 08:52:27.655 2785-2785/com.jends.mcshopplus W/System.err:     at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:97)
2020-07-01 08:52:27.655 2785-2785/com.jends.mcshopplus W/System.err:     at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:89)
2020-07-01 08:52:27.655 2785-2785/com.jends.mcshopplus W/System.err:     at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:63)
2020-07-01 08:52:27.655 2785-2785/com.jends.mcshopplus W/System.err:     at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:73)
2020-07-01 08:52:27.655 2785-2785/com.jends.mcshopplus W/System.err:     at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectWithRetries(ConnectionImpl.java:906)
2020-07-01 08:52:27.655 2785-2785/com.jends.mcshopplus W/System.err:     at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:831)
2020-07-01 08:52:27.656 2785-2785/com.jends.mcshopplus W/System.err:     at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.(ConnectionImpl.java:456)
2020-07-01 08:52:27.656 2785-2785/com.jends.mcshopplus W/System.err:     at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:246)
2020-07-01 08:52:27.656 2785-2785/com.jends.mcshopplus W/System.err:     at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:197)
2020-07-01 08:52:27.656 2785-2785/com.jends.mcshopplus W/System.err:     at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:580)
2020-07-01 08:52:27.656 2785-2785/com.jends.mcshopplus W/System.err:     at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:218)
2020-07-01 08:52:27.656 2785-2785/com.jends.mcshopplus W/System.err:     at com.jends.mcshopplus.MySQLData.openConnection(MySQLData.java:23)
2020-07-01 08:52:27.656 2785-2785/com.jends.mcshopplus W/System.err:     at com.jends.mcshopplus.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:24)
2020-07-01 08:52:27.656 2785-2785/com.jends.mcshopplus W/System.err:     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7957)
2020-07-01 08:52:27.656 2785-2785/com.jends.mcshopplus W/System.err:     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7946)
2020-07-01 08:52:27.657 2785-2785/com.jends.mcshopplus W/System.err:     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1307)
2020-07-01 08:52:27.657 2785-2785/com.jends.mcshopplus W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3530)
2020-07-01 08:52:27.657 2785-2785/com.jends.mcshopplus W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3707)
2020-07-01 08:52:27.657 2785-2785/com.jends.mcshopplus W/System.err:     at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:83)
2020-07-01 08:52:27.657 2785-2785/com.jends.mcshopplus W/System.err:     at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
2020-07-01 08:52:27.657 2785-2785/com.jends.mcshopplus W/System.err:     at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
2020-07-01 08:52:27.657 2785-2785/com.jends.mcshopplus W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2220)
2020-07-01 08:52:27.657 2785-2785/com.jends.mcshopplus W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
2020-07-01 08:52:27.657 2785-2785/com.jends.mcshopplus W/System.err:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:237)
2020-07-01 08:52:27.657 2785-2785/com.jends.mcshopplus W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8016)
2020-07-01 08:52:27.657 2785-2785/com.jends.mcshopplus W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
2020-07-01 08:52:27.658 2785-2785/com.jends.mcshopplus W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
2020-07-01 08:52:27.658 2785-2785/com.jends.mcshopplus W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1076)
2020-07-01 08:52:27.659 2785-2785/com.jends.mcshopplus W/System.err: Caused by: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
2020-07-01 08:52:27.659 2785-2785/com.jends.mcshopplus W/System.err:     at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1565)
2020-07-01 08:52:27.659 2785-2785/com.jends.mcshopplus W/System.err:     at java.net.Inet6AddressImpl.lookupHostByName(Inet6AddressImpl.java:115)
2020-07-01 08:52:27.659 2785-2785/com.jends.mcshopplus W/System.err:     at java.net.Inet6AddressImpl.lookupAllHostAddr(Inet6AddressImpl.java:103)
2020-07-01 08:52:27.660 2785-2785/com.jends.mcshopplus W/System.err:     at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:1152)
2020-07-01 08:52:27.660 2785-2785/com.jends.mcshopplus W/System.err:     at com.mysql.cj.protocol.StandardSocketFactory.connect(StandardSocketFactory.java:132)
2020-07-01 08:52:27.660 2785-2785/com.jends.mcshopplus W/System.err:     at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.NativeSocketConnection.connect(NativeSocketConnection.java:65)
2020-07-01 08:52:27.660 2785-2785/com.jends.mcshopplus W/System.err:     at com.mysql.cj.NativeSession.connect(NativeSession.java:144)
2020-07-01 08:52:27.660 2785-2785/com.jends.mcshopplus W/System.err:     at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectWithRetries(ConnectionImpl.java:850)
2020-07-01 08:52:27.660 2785-2785/com.jends.mcshopplus W/System.err:    ... 23 more

Comment: Please show us the *complete* stacktrace including any nested exceptions.

Comment: MySQL is not running on your Android device. Hence, `localhost` is not the right address. Please note that JDBC is not usually used in Android apps, for reliability and security reasons. Please use some form of middleware, such as a Web service, to go between your Android app and your database.

Comment: i added the error from the console

Comment: Seems it has `NetworkOnMainThreadException`, would you try run on `other thread` ? (If you ensure there is a SQL Server running on your device)